# Background Location Update issue When I minimized my app

Tags: android

When I Minimized my app background location is not updating when it opens it will be updating.

While updating location after few minutes app gets restarted.

```
public  void onLocationChanged(Location location) {

    ArrayList<Activity> activities = new ArrayList<Activity>();

    activities.add(StartTravel.StartTravelActivity);

    boolean isAppRunning = false;
    for (Activity activity : activities) {
        if (activity != null)
            isAppRunning = true;
    }
    if (isAppRunning) {
        startLocationUpdates();
    }
    if (!isAppRunning) {
        startLocationUpdates();
    }
    curLat = location.getLatitude();
    curLng = location.getLongitude();
    curLat1 = location.getLatitude();
    curLng1 = location.getLongitude();

    if (curLat != 0.0 && curLng != 0.0) {
        callWebservice();
    }
    Log.e("IN","Track Location :: " + curLat + curLng);
//  boolean isInserted1 = myDb.INSERT(String.format("%.6f",location.getLatitude()),String.format("%.6f",location.getLongitude()));
}
```

Comment: did you use broadcast receiver for that?

Comment: Possible duplicate 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25755990/pause-location-services-when-app-is-minimized

Comment: almost all of this code could be omitted. 

    if(StartTravel.StartTravelActivity != null)
        startLocationUpdates();

    curLat = location.getLatitude();
    curLng = location.getLongitude();
  
    if(curLat != 0f && curLng != 0f)
        callWebService();

just an observation.

Comment: No i didn't use broadcast receiver - Waleed Asim

Answer (score 0):

try to put your code in onPause().

Answer (score 0):

You need to move the location update code a [`Service`](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/services.html). Activity is not meant for performing a long-running operations in the background.

Moreover, the problem emerge when you're creating a new object in your code with this:

```
public  void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
  ArrayList<Activity> activities = new ArrayList<Activity>();
  activities.add(StartTravel.StartTravelActivity);
}
```

Creating object is expensive for Android. You're trying to allocate a new object each time the location changed. The memory used by the objects you've created is not yet reclaimed by `garbage collector`. So, it will get `Out Of Memory` error then killed by the system.